# HA router with keepalived showing unexpected traceroute

Tags: linux, linux-networking, high-availability

I have a couple of routers in HA using keepalived vrrp daemon under linux.

Here are the addresses

```
x.x.x.129  floating (keepalive)
x.x.x.130  router1 (static)
x.x.x.131  router2 (static)
```

Something is not working properly with these routers.  I shut down router2 and it routes.  If I bring router2 up I can ping all the machines.  Log in via ssh.  But I can't connect out with a browser anymore.  DNS works internally though so it's not DNS.

Anyway, I thought perhaps the traceroute was a little odd.
If I run traceroute, the first hop is x.x.x.130 and not x.x.x.129 despite 129 being set as the gateway address.  Why would that be?

Comment: Nothing unusual about the traceroute. The machine wisely uses its native address as the source address for packets it generates (in this case, the ICMP time exceeded ICMP error) so you can tell what physical machine it came from.

Comment: Thanks, So it's normal behaviour.  There must be some other issue.

Comment: Yes, it's normal. When the device originates packets itself, it won't use the floating address.

Comment: ok that leads onto to another question...